# java hashCode() function on reference variable and objects

Tags: java, hashcode

For example, if I create an A type object,

```
A a = new A();
```

then a is a reference on the Stack that points to a A type object on the heap.
My question is, if I call a.hashCode(), which one's hash code will be returned, the hashcode of the reference or the hashcode of the object?
if it is the hashcode of the object, how can i get the hashcode of the reference?
Could anyone kindly give me some tips plz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hashCode()` is just a non-static method, just like any other non-static method.  It's either defined by `A`, or by a base class of `A` (`Object`, in the worst case).  All that happens is that method gets called on the instance in question.

> how can i get the hashcode of the reference?

You can't, because that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hash code of the reference by calling:

```
System.identityHashCode(a);
```

This is what data structures such as java.util.IdentityHashMap are based on.